# void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, searchview

I am doing SearchView on CustomAdapter where it will search Gate Name. After i try run the app, it suddenly crash and give me the error as stated above. I do not know which part did i even do wrong that cause this issue to appear everytime i try to run my app.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            List<Gate> gateSearchList = new ArrayList<Gate>();

            for (Gate gate : gateList) {
                if (gate.getGateName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                    gateSearchList.add(gate);
                }
            }

            adapter = new GateAdapter(MainActivity.this, gateSearchList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout) {
        logout();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

main_menu.xml

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/item_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Search">

</item>
<item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="Log Out"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

This is the error message in logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)'
>   on a null object reference

It also indicate that the error also came from this line of code:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
```

I hope someone can be able to provide me the solution to solve my issue.

Comment: Sorry, i am not very good in programming. I am just only a student too. So i may instead need some help as i am terrible in fixing error

Comment: Nope. Whats that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `android:actionViewClass` to `app:actionViewClass`, because you are using `SearchView` from support lib

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Search">
```

Comment: OMG. IT WORKS!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Posting this here for others who might face the similar issue.

Following up Jasmin John's Point I Have solved the issue with pro-guard rule by adding

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: @MacaronLover you need to add to your proguard file. [this link should help](https://medium.com/@maheshwar.ligade/enabling-proguard-for-android-98e2b19e90a4)

Comment: @Poorya Does it need to go in the 'proguard-android.txt' file itself or the 'build.gradle' file?

Comment: to proguard-android.txt

Answer (score 2):

**create a one file in** `res/values/xml/searchable.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:hint="search hint"
  android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

**and add this meta data tag in manifest in application tag file like this**

```
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

change your oncreate menu like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.R.id.item_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. The error even indicate something to do with this line: searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

Comment: add logcat with quetion

Comment: Its alright. I found out the issue already. Rajendran managed to found out my error. It was app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView". I put android instead of app. It was my mistake

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. Appreciate the help and guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue my code was working properly when I was debugging it, but when I build an apk and run it crashes.

I used **minifyEnabled false** in build.gradle file and it worked properly

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to disable minify in the release version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem in my Menu.xml file so I've changed this:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

in this:

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot to add this in your (menu-> `yourfilename.xml`)

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

And please, make sure that you are using the same class of `searchview` in your `.java` file as well.