# I have implemented searchview using with recyclerview but I am getting error?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have implemented SearchView with RecyclerView but I am getting an error.
    I am developing android weather app and I want to implement function  when user launch app user can search cityName when the user hits names it should display cityName and weather information a user can also add city add and remove it but I have followed this tutorial for SearchView [searchviewtutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-searchview)

**but I am getting this error**

```
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference
                      at yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.weather.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
```

**I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277654/void-android-support-v7-widget-searchview-setonquerytextlistenerandroid-support?rq=1) but did not solve the issue.**

**below my MainActivity.java file where I have implemented SearchView with Recyclerview**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private List<Weather> weatherArrayList;
        private List<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionList;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private SearchView mSearchView;
        private WeatherAdapter adapter;
        private ConditionAdapter conditionAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data.. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            //Creating an object of our api interface

            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    ApiService api = WeatherClient.getApiService();

                    /**
                     * Calling JSON
                     */
                    Call<List<Weather>> call = api.getWeather("6bed69052a864d44a8e165653183008", "Andijan");


                    /**
                     * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
                     */
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Weather>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<Weather>> call, Response<List<Weather>> response) {
                            //Dismiss Dialog
                            //    Log.d("url", call.request().url().toString());
                            pDialog.dismiss();

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                /**
                                 * Got Successfully
                                 */
                                weatherArrayList = response.body();

                                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

                                LinearLayoutManager eLayoutManager = null;

                                adapter = new WeatherAdapter((List<Weather>) weatherArrayList);
                                eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<Weather>> call, Throwable t) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                   getApi();

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }


        public void getApi(){
            ApiService apiService = WeatherClient.getApiService();
            Call<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionCall = apiService.forecast("6bed69052a864d44a8e165653183008", "Andijan", 5);
            conditionCall.enqueue(new Callback<ForecastEndingPoint>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionCall, Response<ForecastEndingPoint> response) {
                    //Dismiss Dialog
                    //    Log.d("url", call.request().url().toString());
                    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        /**
                         * Got Successfully
                         */
                        conditionList = Collections.singletonList(response.body());

                        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

                        LinearLayoutManager eLayoutManager = null;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        Context picassoContext = getApplicationContext();
                        conditionAdapter = new ConditionAdapter(conditionList, context, picassoContext);
                        eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(conditionAdapter);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionCall, Throwable t) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
        }
```

**below my activity_main.xml file where I have hosted recyclerview.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**below search.xml where I have implemented Searchview**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:queryHint="Search Here"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see in the tutorial it's "SearchView", not "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView". Change it to "SearchView".

Comment: it is still crashes

Comment: @Prishanth Verma Process: yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.weather, PID: 4012
android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: I think the problem is your searchView is in different xml than "activity_main.xml". So it couldn't find it. According to the tutorial SearchView and Recycler View are in the same layout right?. Why are you using different layouts?

Comment: @Prishanth Verma, yes I am using I am using in search.xml

Comment: What do you mean?. If you put searchView in "activity_main", u wont get the error anymore

Comment: @Prishant it is loading data only not it is showing progress bar

Comment: @Prishant sharma I have put activity_main.xml file

Comment: Did you put the "searchView" in "activity_main"?. Try running it once

Comment: it is loading only progress bar

Comment: Dude i dont see progress bar in your layout that you had put it in the question

Comment: please check below searchView

Comment: Check the question, there is no progressbar in your layout

Comment: check Oncreate method

Comment: @below searchView

Comment: sorry, i was checking in the xml

Comment: @check mainactivity oncreate method

Comment: Do one thing, remove this code "pDialog.show()" and see

Comment: it is showing only searchView not recyclerView maybe I will posted my github code I have been trying almost five days

Comment: Are there any items in the recycler view?, otherwise nothing will be shown

Answer (score 0):

That's an simple null pointer exception. you did not share the whole error but at the end off the error you get some line number where the error come from.just click on that and compiler automatically direct to that line.
make sure that you did not using any variable with out initializing it. 
write`list<Weather> = new ArrayList()` instead of just writing `list<Weather>`.